# Downgrade ruby version in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I am using windows. When I type `ruby -v` I get: `ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]`

I want to downgrade the ruby version to 2.2.3 how can I do that?

As mysql2 gem works on ruby version < 2.6.

Comment: How did you install your current Ruby version? Why do you thing that the `mysql2` doesn't work with Ruby 2.6?

Comment: @spickermann When I tried to mysql2. I says: `Fetching: mysql2-0.5.2-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        mysql2 requires Ruby version < 2.6, >= 2.0.`

Comment: There are multiple ways to use Ruby on Windows and knowing how to downgrade depends entirely on how you installed it. The installer? Cygwin? Mingw? WSL?

Comment: mysql2 version 0.5.2 is about two years old. Did you consider updating that gem to the latest version? [0.5.3](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions/0.5.3-x86-mingw32) supports Ruby 2.6. Upgrading this old gem is probably better than trying to downgrade to a version of Ruby that is almost five years old.

Comment: I'd be shocked if there were a reliable way to install Ruby 2.2 on Windows in 2020, so I'm gonna agree with spickermann that you need to upgrade the gem.